# rails 4 routing, remove default para

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-routing

I have some problem with rails 4 routing. Currently the routing is like this.

```
  analytic_practiceday_path  POST    /analytics/:analytic_id/practiceday(.:format)   analytics#practiceday
  analytic_practiceuser_path GET     /analytics/:analytic_id/practiceuser(.:format) analytics#practiceuser
```

I would like to have the `:analytic_id` part to be removed. So it will look like this

```
  analytic_practiceday_path  POST    /analytics/practiceday  analytics#practiceday
  analytic_practiceuser_path GET     /analytics/practiceuser analytics#practiceuser
```

My current code is

```
resources :analytics, :only =>"index" do
    post 'practiceday', to: "analytics#practiceday"
    get 'practiceuser', to: "analytics#practiceuser"
end
```

I know it is possible to declare it explicitly,

```
get '/analytic/practiceday', to: "analytics#practiceday", as: "analytic_practice_day"
```

But I have 20~30 routes to be defined. I would appreciate if anyone can tell me a better way to do it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about :

```
resources :analytics, only: :index do
  collection do
    post :practiceday
    get  :practiceuser
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
post 'practiceday', to: "analytics#practiceday", on: :collection
```

Edit: This will reverse the linguistic order of your routes from analytic_practiceday_path to practiceday_analytic_path. I don't know if that's a deal breaker for you. If so, you may be forced to specify each route with :as.